How to install tor on Ubuntu 24.04
I tried to install tor on my fresh installed ubuntu 24.04.
But I run into serveral problems.
Can not add tor to sources.list.
Does anyone know the exact entry for /etc/apt/sources.list
Secondly there is a problem with libssl.
Tor wants libssl1.1 but 24.04 has only libssl3.
How to overcome these issues?

For ubuntu 24.04, open the terminal and run the following commands:
sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 74A941BA219EC810
sudo gpg --export 74A941BA219EC810 | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg > /dev/null
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org noble main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tor torbrowser-launcher


For libssl1.1 I found an answer. I had to download the old package and install it manually.
curl -O http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22_amd64.deb

dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22_amd64.deb


I was able to install Tor on my Ubuntu 24.04 Server with the following modified /etc/apt/sources.list :
deb     [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main

and following the rest of the instructions on the Debian Installation page

Ubuntu 24.04 is noble, but this answer show that it relies on jammy (Ubuntu 22.04). Is it intentional? You can quote the commands in your answer so that it doesn't rely on an external resource.

It's working for me in 24.04.  Here's my notes:
Install the launcher
sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher

This sets it ready so it can be made usable by each ID individually.
Tor for a specific ID (after the above install)
Run torbrowser-launcher
A copy of the TOR browser will be downloaded for that specific ID's use.

I dont want the torbrowser. I run ubuntu 24.04 as a server without gui.
